# "useLoaderData must be used within a data router" appears only when testing with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router

With React Router v6.14.2 I have done all the steps to set up a browser router

**index.jsx**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <ProfileList />,
        loader: profileListLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
```

Then when I want to use the data loader in my react component it looks like this

**profileList.jsx**

```
const ProfileList: React.FC = () => {
  const users = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div data-testid={"profiles"}>
      {users.map((user: User) => (
        <Link to={`/profile/${user.id}`}>
          <ProfileDetailView user={user} />
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export const profileListLoader = async () => {
  return fakeUsers as User[];
};

export default ProfileList;
```

This works great when running the App locally, the users are loading and I have zero issues in the console or otherwise.

However when I try to run the jest tests I get the error
`useLoaderData must be used within a data router` 
and it points to the line
`const users = useLoaderData();`

The test currently is very simple, but this is still causing it to fail.

**profile.test.js**

```
test("Render profile list", () => {
  beforeEach(() => fetch.mockClear());
  render(<ProfileList />);
  const profileList = screen.getByTestId("profiles");
  expect(profileList).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I tried checking the react router documentation and following along closely. I have searched in stack overflow but have not found anything that matches my problem exactly.

Comment: "Testing react router" -> https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/

Answer (score 2):

Even in unit tests the components accessing the Data APIs should still be rendered within a Data router. In unit tests it is recommended to use the `MemoryRouter` (*e.g. [`createMemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-memory-router)*) since Node isn't a DOM environment.

Example:

```
test("Render profile list", () => {
  beforeEach(() => fetch.mockClear());

  const router = createMemoryRouter(
    [{ path: "/", element: <ProfileList /> }],
    { initialEntries: ["/"] },
  );

  render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);

  const profileList = screen.getByTestId("profiles");
  expect(profileList).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```